# .Net Charts not displaying in IE (X-Content-Type-Options)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, dundas

This is a really weird issue i am having. I produce a chart dynamically using .NET chart library and it has been working for about a year all of a sudden its has stopped working in Internet Explorer (IE) but works in Chrome and also Edge. I use .NET and also Dundas in another part of the systems to also produce a charts and these work fine.

The site is available on multiple environments and the chart works within the UAT area in IE.

This is what is displayed on screen and help would be appreciated

[image]

---

Update

When removing the following http header X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff the chart works, does anyone know how i could get round this as i need to keep this header in for penetration testing compliance.

---

Update

I have found the line of code that is causing the issue but i am unsure how to get round it as i still require the hyperlink

`uxChart1.Series["Series1"].Points[k].Url = "Charts.aspx?sid=" + id;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after trying various methods.

If setting the URL on the Points in the Series and having the X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff HTTP Response Header set it doesn't seem to like the Chart ImageType being set to a 'Bmp' so i have changed this to a 'Jpeg' and now it displays

Comment: I be interested if anyone knows why bmp causes an issue.